# How to select only records that have number in column (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I want to do this:

I want to return a record set converting one nvarchar value (ID) to an integer if it contains a number.  If ID can be converted to a number, then add that row to the `SELECT` record set.  If not, skip that row.

I think the SQL should look something like this.

(ID is nvarchar(10)  in dbo.Table)

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp  (ID int)
INSERT INTO #Temp SELECT ID FROM Table Where ISNumeric(Id)=0
```

But I get an error:  nvarchar value 'Default' to data type int.  If I do a `SELECT CAST(ID as int)` that does not work either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To be safe, forget about ISNUMERIC

If you are not expecting negative numbers, you can use this

```
INSERT INTO #Temp SELECT ID FROM Table
Where Id > ''  -- is not the empty string and is not null
  AND not ID like '%[^0-9]%'  -- contains digits only
```

Comment: Why is `NOT` necessary here?  If we're selecting records with digits only, then why use `NOT`?

Comment: @LearneR because '^' is negation and [^0-9] means a non-digit char. Without NOT we get IDs that have at least one non-digit char

Answer (score 12):

`ISNumeric(Id)=0`  should be `ISNumeric(Id)=1`

However ISNUMERIC has a problem

run this

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('2d5'), ISNUMERIC('-'), ISNUMERIC('+')
```

Those all return 1

Take a look at [IsNumeric, IsInt, IsNumber](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber) for some ways to figure out if it can be converted to an integer

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this one could help:

```
select column_desired from requested_table <> 0 or is not null
```